# How can I change the size of the 'View Report' button?

Tags: ssrs-2008

How can I make the size of the 'View Report' button in the report viewer control  larger? I wrote some Javascript to make it bigger initially, but then once different parameters were selected and the 'View Report' button was clicked again it would revert to the old size.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this quickly and it seems to have worked...

the Id of my submit button is ctl31_ctl04_ctl00, so I went into the style sheet and added:

```
#ctl31_ctl04_ctl00
{
    font-size:36px;
    background-color:#000;

}
```

Not sure if that would always be the Id though so it might be dangerous if you are going to deploy this in production.

I also got it working in firefox by using the attribute selector as follows:

```
input[type="submit"] {...}
```

but it doesn't work in IE for some reason.  I need to look at why not since it should work I think based on the DOCTYPE and I am using IE9